# Do not load the textures on the obj model in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

You can help, why the texture does not load

I tried to load the texture on a separate mesh in obj but for some reason it does not load and gives an error can anyone tell what the reason is
material is applied but the texture is why there is no

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);

var textureBody = new THREE.Texture();

loader.load('tex/Base4.png', function(image) {
  textureBody.image = image;
  textureBody.needsUpdate = true;
});

var meshes = [];    
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

objLoader.load('models/bas.obj', function(object) {
  console.log(object);

  object.traverse(function(child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      meshes.push(child);
    }
  });

  var body = meshes[2];

  body.position.y = 2;

  scene.add(body);

  var bumpMapBody = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('tex/untitled2-NM_u0_v0.tif');

  body.material = new THREE.MeshPhonglMaterial({

    map: textureBody
  });
});
```

This gives an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: THREE.MeshPhonglMaterial is not a constructor
>   at mucode.js:77    "body.material = new THREE.MeshPhonglMaterial({"at Object.onLoad (OBJLoader.js:385)
>   at XMLHttpRequest. (three.js:32008)

ps
Does anyone know how to shrink the window and move the canvas to a separate div

Comment: Please ask separate questions in separate posts.

Comment: "MeshPhonglMaterial" should probably be "MeshPhongMaterial"

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code. It's not `MeshPhonglMaterial` but `MeshPhongMaterial`.

Comment: Please accept/upvote the answer if it was helpful to you.